# add +- 1 year in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try to select the Products that has a yearmodel between +1 and -1 the current year. And I only want the Year (ex 2011) not the full date and time.

```
SELECT ProductName FROM tblProduct WHERE Year BETWEEN 
year(getdate()+1) AND year(getdate()-1)
```

Does not work, but something similar maybe...

Comment: select year(getdate()+1) => 2011. this seems to be working ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are adding the 1 to getdate() so you are adding 1 day

```
   SELECT ProductName FROM tblProduct WHERE Year BETWEEN 
    (year(getdate()) -1) AND (year(getdate()) + 1)
```

Comment: Small correction: (year(getdate()) - 1) AND (year(getdate()) + 1)

Answer (score 20):

```
SELECT dateadd(year, -1, getdate())
```

Would have done:

```
SELECT productname 
FROM tblproduct 
WHERE [year] between (select dateadd(year, -1, getdate()) AND (select dateadd(year, +1, getdate())
```